# Yet another FizzBuzz

Tags: c++, c++11, functional-programming, fizzbuzz

Since today is apparently a good day for...unlikely FizzBuzz implementations, I decided to contribute another, this one in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include "xrange.h"

int main() {
    std::vector<std::function<void(int)> > funcs {
        [](int i) { std::cout << i << "\n"; },
        [](int i) { std::cout << "fizz\n";  },
        [](int i) { std::cout << "buzz\n";  },
        [](int i) { std::cout << "fizzbuzz\n"; }
    };

    auto test = [](int i){return (i % 3 == 0) + 2 * (i % 5 == 0); };

    for (auto i : xrange(1, 101))
        funcs[test(i)](i);
}
```

This uses the same `xrange` I posted in [a previous answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/55533/489).

I'd be particularly interested in eliminating having to use `test`, but a sequence like: `[[` is parsed as introducing an attribute rather than using the return from a lambda as an index (and inserting white space doesn't seem to help). I could use `.at()` instead, but that imposes runtime overhead I'd also rather avoid.

Comment: Did you try extra paranthesis: `funcs[([]...)]`? Note that anything using a lambda in the index brackets is basically obfuscation.

Comment: @Nobody: Yes, I did, but couldn't find a way g++ would accept it.

Comment: As it is already ugly with the lambda you could get it to work with some arithmetic: `funcs[0+[](int...` and when talking about ugliness you could also use the explicit operator name: `funcs.operator[]([]...`

Comment: @Nobody: Neither of these options strikes me as an improvement (but opinions obviously vary--I don't find lambdas ugly at all).

Comment: So you say that (if it would work) you would prefer to use:`funcs[[](int i){return (i % 3 == 0) + 2 * (i % 5 == 0); }(i)]` over `funcs[(i % 3 == 0) + 2 * (i % 5 == 0)]` (which is already a mess)?

Comment: @Nobody: You do have a point that the lambda doesn't contribute much in that case.

Comment: Btw: `funcs[([](int i){return (i % 3 == 0) + 2 * (i % 5 == 0);}(i))](i);` works on my g++ 4.9.0 (so does `funcs[([](int i){return (i % 3 == 0) + 2 * (i % 5 == 0);})(i)](i);`) with `-Wall and -pedantic`.

Comment: What's your goal? What kind of improvements would you like to hear?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'd be inclined to make a simple fixed array instead of a `std::vector` for `funcs`:

```
const std::function<void(int i)> funcs[] {
    [](int i) { std::cout << i << "\n"; },
    [](int ) { std::cout << "fizz\n";  },
    [](int ) { std::cout << "buzz\n";  },
    [](int ) { std::cout << "fizzbuzz\n"; }
};
```

This is useful because it eliminates the overhead of memory allocations for a `std::vector` and the calls for constructor and destructor.  As an embedded systems guy, I tend to think about whether code can be in ROM rather than RAM, and whether work can be done at compile-time rather than run-time.

Note, too that I've omitted the variable name for the last three lambdas.  There's no real difference except that it prevents the compiler from generating a warning about "unused parameter `i`" in those three lines.

Also, I think you're overthinking the lambda.  The `test` lambda isn't really necessary at all since you can call it like this:

```
funcs[ (i % 3 == 0) + 2 * (i % 5 == 0) ](i);
```

So (without `xrange.h`, although one could use that also) it would look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

int main() {
    const std::function<void(int i)> funcs[] {
        [](int i) { std::cout << i << "\n"; },
        [](int ) { std::cout << "fizz\n";  },
        [](int ) { std::cout << "buzz\n";  },
        [](int ) { std::cout << "fizzbuzz\n"; }
    };

    for (int i=1; i <= 100; ++i)
        funcs[ (i % 3 == 0) + 2 * (i % 5 == 0) ](i);
}
```

Comment: Are you using a C-style array for brevity, or because you're trying to avoid giving it an explicit size?

Comment: @Jamal: updated my answer to address your question.

Comment: I meant `std::array`, actually (sorry, I should've made that clear).

Comment: @Jamal: `std::array` and a C-style array would be very similar in this context, but I used the C-style array just because it seems to me to be a clearer way to express the idea.  Memory usage and performance would likely be identical, so we can attribute the choice to aesthetic preference.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I figured (so it does answer my question).

Comment: We could attribute the choice to aesthetic preference, or we could logically think about it for one nanosecond.

Comment: @DeadMG: What do you mean?

Comment: C arrays allow a bunch of tremendously unsafe conversions like to raw pointer implicitly, don't behave as values for no good reason, and don't offer useful interfaces like begin() and end(). `std::array` is better in basically every way. And furthermore, if your goal is to avoid overhead, apart from this being a terrible micro-optimization, the std::function probably costs way more than the std::vector.

Comment: None of those are relevant to this particular use.

Comment: If only you could somehow introduce a mind-reading filter into your answer so that only people with this exact use in mind could read it. Also, I think that there's a solid case for saying that since there's also no relevant reason to prefer a C array, one should stick with std::array as that is the superior option in basically every case where it matters.

Comment: Please remember to [be nice](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61824/discussion-between-edward-and-deadmg).